# Calculate changelog against a commit in jenkins using git-plugin

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-github-plugin

I am using Jenkins Git-Plugin to checkout in my CI pipeline. I want to generate changelog between the COMMIT and a predefined REF_COMMIT.

Is there a way to achieve this using [changelog-extensions](https://github.com/jenkinsci/git-plugin#changelog-extensions)? I can see there is option to calculate change log against branch (refs/remote/branch) but nothing written for commits.

Is there any other way i can show the changelogs as git-plugin does in the build without using this changelog-extenstions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a git question per se, not a Jenkins question.

The following may work for you:

```
git whatchanged --no-abbrev -M "--format=commit %H%ntree %T%nparent %P%nauthor %aN <%aE> %ai%ncommitter %cN <%cE> %ci%n%n%w(76,4,4)%s%n%n%b" -n 1024 ${COMMIT} ^${REF_COMMIT}
```

To use it in Jenkins, wrap the above in `sh "..."` while in `script`.

Comment: Thanks @Marat. With this command it's straight forward to calculate the change logs. But to show it in HTML format in jenkins build it slightly difficult. I came across https://github.com/jenkinsci/git-changelog-plugin which comes with some handy options to generate HTML page out from differences.